# Обновление в скролле вниз и вверх в SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, прокрутка, swiperefreshlayout

У меня есть SwipeRefreshLayout и в нем ListView. Так вот когда я делаю скролл вниз и в самом начале появляется иконка обновления то есть обновляется нормально...
Это я делаю так:

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            ToastUtils.ToastLong(ctx, "список заказов обновлен");
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Так вот мне еще нужно обновлять когда скролишь вниз и в конце списка тоже чтобы появлялась иконка и обновлялось, и когда activity создается то есть в onCreate тоже обновление было, как все это реализовать, не смог на буржуйских найти, ибо сформулировать на англ не легко...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сформулировать очень даже легко:

> android swiperefreshlayout top bottom

По [этому запросу](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20swiperefreshlayout%20top%20bottom) в первой ссылке найден [вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867204/swiperefreshlayout-pull-from-bottom), в котором найден [второй ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29740350/1568530) со [ссылкой на библиотеку](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout).
Подключать так:

```
compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.3@aar'
```

Добавить в разметку так:

```
<com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipyrefreshlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srl_direction="both">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout>
```

П. С. На поиск решения затрачено 28 секунд. *28 секунд, Карл! (с)*

Comment: Не могли бы вы посмотреть на этот вопрос?  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516871/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2-swiperefreshlayout