# Не скролится вниз в SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: java, android, прокрутка

Я использую [OrangeGangsters SwipyRefreshLayout](https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/SwipyRefreshLayout) и когда при скролле вверх тоже не срабтывало скролл ListView а срабатывал SwipyRefreshLayout, то есть обновление. Я эту ошибку исправил:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            boolean enable = false;
            if (listView != null && listView.getChildCount() > 0) {
                boolean firstItemVisible = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0;
                boolean topOfFirstItemVisible = listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0;
                enable = firstItemVisible && topOfFirstItemVisible ;
            }
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(enable);
        }
    });
```

Теперь ошибка наоборот вниз не работает, срабатывает SwipeRefreshLayout;

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/five_dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/etOnline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="В сети"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/offlineMessageRelative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/main_dark_bg"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/edit_text_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/edit_text_padding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/offline_message"
            android:textColor="@color/background_color_light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/mainLargeSize" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srl_direction="both">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/five_dp"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/five_dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/five_dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:listSelector="@color/transparent_color"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
    </LinearLayout>
</com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/three_dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbars_shadow" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:background="@drawable/online_default"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: не понятно, зачем вы городите свои костыли? Библиотека и без нихх работает

Comment: В том то и дело, что он срабатывает там, где нужно скроллить ListView, то есть обновлятся нужно только в начале где уже дальше уже скролить нечего и в конце... А у меня он срабатывает везде не позволяя скролится ListView... Скролл вверх я уже решил, теперь осталось скролл вниз...

Comment: покажите XML файл леяута

Comment: Добавил, проверьте пожалуйста...

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете его не по инструкции. Внутри `SwipyRefreshLayout` должен быть `ListView`, а не `LinearLayout`. Поэому у вас работает неправильно. Вот так должно быть:

```
<com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipyrefreshlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srl_direction="both">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</com.orangegangsters.github.swipyrefreshlayout.library.SwipyRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Не помогло, та же проблема...

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно зачем библиотека для этого. Можно же просто [поменять место показа](https://github.com/mohaxspb/TProger/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/kuchanov/tproger/fragment/FragmentCategory.java) кружочка на экране:

```
//вверху
int actionBarSize = ...;
swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewEndTarget(false, actionBarSize);
//внизу
int screenHeight = ...;
swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewEndTarget(false, screenHeight - actionBarSize * 2);
//запускаем отображение
//workaround from
//http://stackoverflow.com/a/26910973/3212712
swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(isLoading);
    }
});
```

А вообще `SwipeRefreshLayout` такой баганутый (и баги в нё с каждым апдейтом возрождаются), что  его лучше вообще не использовать.

Последняя адекватная версия этого виджета находится в либах версии 23.3.0 и 23.1.1. Версии до и в промежутке - с [багами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/497161/17609).

Comment: "Можно же просто поменять место показа кружочка на экране" .
Чтобы и в начале и в конце было обновление по скроллу

Comment: @Omuradil, В начале обновление по дефолту встроено, а для вконце слушателем скрола вызывайте. [Например](https://github.com/mohaxspb/TProger/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/kuchanov/tproger/RecyclerViewOnScrollListener.java)

Comment: Во избежание всех предложенных вами извращений какраз и существует библиотека

Comment: @metalurgus, и в ней поправлены все баги стандартного виджета?.. Просто мне сомнительными кажутся все либы, на коих "лайков" меньше пары тысяч)